# what does "somebody has been cut" mean if this appears in a conversation between two people

Tags: meaning

I came across this phrase in a book I'm reading. In the context it seems to mean one party misunderstands the other party's meaning.

Is there a formal explanation on "cut" in a conversation context?

Thanks,

Comment: You'll need to give us the context to determine if one party has severed the  other party's head or merely kicked him off the team.

Comment: Actually this is from A Feast for Crows and it goes like this: "Is that what they say?" Cersei smiled. "How foolish. I have never looked upon you as a rival, not even for a moment." "I am so pleased to hear that" The girl did not seem to realize that she has been cut

Comment: See below ---->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have transformed the passage into dialog thus:

> Margaery [to Cersei]: There must be some things I could do to help
>   you. It would put to rest all this talk that you and I are rivals for
>   the king.
>
> Cersei [smiling]: Is that what they say? How foolish. I have never
>   looked upon you as a rival, not even for a moment.
>
> Margaery: I am so pleased to hear that.
>
> The girl [Margaery] did not seem to realize that she **had been cut**
>   [by Cersei].

Cersei does not consider Margaery a rival and tells her so. Cersei is really saying is that she doesn't consider Margaery worthy enough to be rival, "not even for a moment." Margaery interprets this as an expression of friendship, but it's really an insult, a **cutting** remark intended to wound, but Margaery doesn't realize that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and reformatting. So **cut** here means insult and a **cutting** remark means an insulting remarks.

Comment: @Lys A cutting remark is one intended to hurt.  Margaery doesn't realize the intent of the Cersei's words, but perhaps she'll think back on it later and feel wounded by the unkind remark.  The result is the cut; the words of insult are the inflicting weapon.